# Android Download and Open PDF File from URL ending with .aspx

Tags: android, asp.net, pdf, android-webview, pdf-viewer

I am able to download and view from url ending with *.pdf with the below code

```
 private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory){
    try {

        URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        //urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0 ){
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but I have tried to download PDF  file  with url ending with .aspx as its generate PDF dynamically and its not working .

I have also tried to embed with webview with google doc url "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+URL  but its also not working.

Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 0):

'.aspx' Is [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) page that is actually web form.

> Web forms are contained in files with a ".aspx" extension; these files
>   typically contain static (X)HTML markup or component markup.

So what you are loading is a simple `HTML` page rendered on server side. So you cannot use it to view `PDF` - in PDF viewer.

Instead of openning '.aspx' from file load this url into `WebView` - this will work only if there are no additional security on the site you are pointing to.

In case of Google Docs the link you are providing to the `WebView` should be sharing links like following:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/view?usp=sharing

Where `x`'s are part of hash. To get this link - click on `Share` option for the document and then `get shareable link`.

Before `WebView` reaches pdf document it could receive few redirects that potentially will be handled by Android itself. To avoid this you need to override `WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading` like in following example:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
mWebView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/file/d/xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/view?usp=sharing");
```

Also you could get direct link to the file using sharable url you get above:

```
change this:
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/view?usp=sharing
to this:
  https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
or to this:
  https://docs.google.com/document/d/xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/export?format=pdf
```

Comment: I have tried all the above URL but its not working .

Comment: the data in HTML is blob data which is generated dynamically and embed in HTML

Comment: Please provide real links that you have used so I could properly answer your question